# Why won't my python3 file import even though it is in the same directory?

Tags: python-3.x

I was attempting to import a python script that was in the same directory and it would not be recognized.

```
import 1PythonScript

def do_stuff() -> None:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove digits from the start of the filename.

Comment: Yes, because module names must be valid identifiers and can't start with a digit.